# Control fan speed (CPU)

Tags: c#, bios

I would like to control the CPU fan completely. Stop it, start it.. do anything. I know there are applications that can do it so I was wondering if you know of any APIs that could be implemented as I am understanding that .NET does not directly give you full control.

Thank you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity ... What application do you know of that can do this? And are they manufacturer independent?

Comment: I barely believe that anyone would let that happen. The outcome could be disastrous for the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the suitable API is the WMI (Framework namespace System.Management): http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms257340(v=vs.80).aspx

> Using the .NET Framework namespace System.Management, you can develop
>   applications in C#, Microsoft® Visual Basic® .NET, or Microsoft J#
>   that obtain enterprise data and automate administrative tasks using
>   Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI). You can also develop
>   applications that provide data to WMI classes using the
>   System.Management.Instrumentation namespace.

Take a look at this CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18268/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-3-Hardw

Answer (score 0):

This will be very specific to your hardware platform.  It depends what the fan control signals are hooked to.  They could be hooked to the chipset, the Super I/O, or a [separate SMbus fun controler](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/2149).  You would need to figure out how it is attached, and then read the datasheets for the chip to figure out how to interface with it.

Once you know how to talk to the device, you could use a toolkit like [WinIO](http://www.internals.com/) to talk to the registers.